# javascript - conditional javascript object ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a payload which may or may not contain a value.

```js
const { mainValue } = payload;
```

This `mainValue` can either only be `optionaA` or `optionB`.

I am constructing another object based on this value. How can I conditionally construct the below object. Either I need `newProp1` or just `newProp2`. Is there an ES6 way of doing it, which will be neater.

```js
const newObj = {
    propertyA: someValue,
    AttributeA: {
        newProp1: {
            value: optionaA
        },
        //// i need newProp1 or newProp2 in this newObj
        newProp2: {
            value: optionaB
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"may or may not contain a value"_... are you saying that `mainValue` could also be `undefined`? If so, what should the result look like in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the smallest amount of code you can have that will produce the desired output is:

```
const { mainValue } = payload
const newObj = {
  propertyA: someValue,
  AttributeA: {
    [`newProp${mainValue === optionaA ? 1 : 2`]: {
      value: mainValue
    }
  }
}
```

The ES6 feature that enables it is [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: `${
                mainValue === 'optionaA' || 'otherOption' 'email' ? '1' : '2'
              }``
How can I fit an OR statement?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the statement above. Do you mean that mainValue can be optionaA, otherOption or email and in any of this cases it should add to newProp1 and otherwise to newProp2?